# Intent onChildClickListener issue

Tags: android, expandablelistview

My app is working until I click one of the child element in my expandablelist view.And I don't know why because everything is looking like fine.Here is my main activity:

```
  expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    expListView2 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp2);
    expListView3 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp3);
    expListView4 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp4);
    expListView5 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp5);


    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    listAdapter2 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader2, listDataChild2);
    listAdapter3 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader3, listDataChild3);
    listAdapter4 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader4, listDataChild4);
    listAdapter5 = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader5, listDataChild5);



    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    expListView2.setAdapter(listAdapter3);
    expListView3.setAdapter(listAdapter4);
    expListView4.setAdapter(listAdapter5);
    expListView5.setAdapter(listAdapter2);

    expListView5.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), internet_sonet_adsl.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, internet_sonet_fiber.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, internet_sonet_yalin_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, internet_sonet_uydu_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, internet_tum_paketler.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, internet_sonet_fiber_nerede.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 6) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, internet_hizmet_karsilastirma.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 1) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), servisler_guvenlik.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, servisler_bulut_bilisim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, servisler_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, servisler_mobil_servisler.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, servisler_sonet_teknoloji.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 2) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), kampanya_sonet_adsl.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, kampanya_sonet_airfiber.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, kampanya_sonet_fiber.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, kampanya_sonet_yalin_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, kampanya_sonet_uydu_internet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 3) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), senindunyan_guvenli_evim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, senindunyan_guvenli_isim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, senindunyan_akilli_evim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, senindunyan_akilli_isim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, senindunyan_tum_paketler.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, senindunyan_sonet_akilli_tv.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 6) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, senindunyan_sikca_sorulan_sorular.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 5) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cihazlar_sikca_sorulan_sorular.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cihazlar_sonet_musterilerine_ozel.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            if (groupPosition == 6) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), destek_fatura_islemleri.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, destek_satis_noktalari.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, destek_bize_ulasin.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, destek_televizyon.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, destek_iletisim.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, destek_sosyal_medya_sonet.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 6) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, destek_bolge_cozum_ortakligi.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });



}
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    listDataHeader2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild2 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    listDataHeader3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild3 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    listDataHeader4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild4 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    listDataHeader5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild5 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Internet");

    listDataHeader2.add("Internet");
    listDataHeader2.add("Servisler");
    listDataHeader2.add("Kampanya");
    listDataHeader2.add("Senin Dünyan");
    listDataHeader2.add("TV");
    listDataHeader2.add("Cihazlar");
    listDataHeader2.add("Destek");

    listDataHeader3.add("Cihazlar");

    listDataHeader4.add("Servisler");

    listDataHeader5.add("Diğer");


    // Adding child data
    List<String> internett = new ArrayList<String>();
    internett.add("Sonet ADSL");
    internett.add("Sonet Fiber");
    internett.add("Sonet Yalın İnternet");
    internett.add("Sonet Uydu İnternet");
    internett.add("Tüm Paketler");
    internett.add("Sıkça Sorulan Sorular");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> servislerr = new ArrayList<String>();
    servislerr.add("Güvenlik");
    servislerr.add("Bulut Bilişim");
    servislerr.add("İnternet");
    servislerr.add("Mobil Servisler");
    servislerr.add("Sonet Teknoloji");

    List<String> cihazlarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    cihazlarr.add("Sıkça Sorulan Sorular");
    cihazlarr.add("Sonet Müşterilerine Özel");

    List<String> diğer = new ArrayList<String>();
    diğer.add("Senin Dünyan");
    diğer.add("Sonetlilere Özel");
    diğer.add("Destek");

    List<String> internet = new ArrayList<String>();
    internet.add("Sonet ADSL");
    internet.add("Sonet FIBER");
    internet.add("Sonet Yalın Internet");
    internet.add("Sonet Uydu Internet");
    internet.add("Tüm Paketler");
    internet.add("Sonet Fiber Nerede?");
    internet.add("Hizmet Karşılaştırma");


    List<String> servisler = new ArrayList<String>();
    servisler.add("Güvenlik");
    servisler.add("Bulut Bilişim");
    servisler.add("Internet");
    servisler.add("Mobil Servisler");
    servisler.add("Sonet Teknoloji");

    List<String> kampanya = new ArrayList<String>();
    kampanya.add("Sonet ADSL");
    kampanya.add("Sonet AirFiber");
    kampanya.add("Sonet Fiber");
    kampanya.add("Sonet Yalın Internet");
    kampanya.add("Sonet Uydu Internet");



    List<String> senindünyan = new ArrayList<String>();
    senindünyan.add("Güvenli Evim");
    senindünyan.add("Güvenli İşim");
    senindünyan.add("Akıllı Evim");
    senindünyan.add("Akıllı İşim");
    senindünyan.add("Tüm Paketler");
    senindünyan.add("Sonet Akıllı TV");
    senindünyan.add("Sıkça Sorulan Sorular");

    List<String> tv = new ArrayList<String>();


    List<String> cihazlar = new ArrayList<String>();
    cihazlar.add("Sıkça Sorulan Sorular");
    cihazlar.add("Sonet Müşterilerine Özel");

    List<String> destek = new ArrayList<String>();
    destek.add("Fatura İşlemleri");
    destek.add("Satış Noktaları");
    destek.add("Bize Ulaşın");
    destek.add("Televizyon");
    destek.add("İletişim");
    destek.add("Sosyal Medya Sonet");
    destek.add("Bölge Çözüm Ortaklığı!");



    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), internett); // Header, Child data

    listDataChild3.put(listDataHeader3.get(0), servislerr); // Header, Child data

    listDataChild4.put(listDataHeader4.get(0), cihazlarr); // Header, Child data

    listDataChild5.put(listDataHeader5.get(0), diğer); // Header, Child data


    listDataChild2.put(listDataHeader2.get(0), internet); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild2.put(listDataHeader2.get(1), servisler);
    listDataChild2.put(listDataHeader2.get(2), kampanya);
    listDataChild2.put(listDataHeader2.get(3), senindünyan);
    listDataChild2.put(listDataHeader2.get(4), tv);
    listDataChild2.put(listDataHeader2.get(5), cihazlar);
    listDataChild2.put(listDataHeader2.get(6), destek);
}
```

}

And here is my adapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
```

{

```
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

So what can be the my problem?
ANy help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post error what you get ?

Comment: Ah okay I solved my problem,by looking at the error.It was a so simple mistake that I forgot to add intent on my androidmanifest.Thanks for reminding me to looking at the error :))